# React Native with firebase java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq

Tags: java, android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am following the tutorial [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/auth/android)

and also checked a similar issue on stack overflow
[Android 3.1.1 - Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818415/android-3-1-1-failed-resolution-of-lcom-google-android-gms-common-internal-zz)

so my firebase libraries are using same versions already.

here is the error

```
06-16 18:46:28.987 18430-18430/com.myProject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.myProject, PID: 18430
                                                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5965)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5557)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5496)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1594)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6239)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myProject-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.myProject-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.myProject-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5965) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5557) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5496) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1594) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6239) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

and this is my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    compile project(':realm')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')

    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules


    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0"
    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'


    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what is the problem, I mistakenly reference to the wrong documentation. The RN-Firebase I am using is 3.0.1, the version really matter..