# Which dependency is causing "Failed resolution Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab;"

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, react-native

I am NOT using firebase, which seems to be the cause of the problem for [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322864/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-failed-resolution-of-lcom-goo) [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887240/react-native-with-firebase-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of) 
Here is screenshot of the error:

[image]

Here is my dependency list:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-connectivity-status')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
    implementation project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-spinkit')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-picker')
    implementation 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'
    implementation project(':blelibrary')
    implementation project(':gaialibrary')
    implementation project(':vmupgradelibrary')
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation project(':react-native-connectivity-status')

    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1")
}
```

and more information

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.someapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 28
        versionName "1.2.4"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the best way to determine which dependencies are causing the error to appear?

Here's the build.gradle at the root level.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // 4.2.0 is the latest version of com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 as of Jan 15, 2019

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                    details.useVersion '15.0.1'
                }
            }
        }
        // Add jitpack repository (added by react-native-spinkit)
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()

        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }

}
```

I've also updated the Main.Application.java file as instructed by Andrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `implementation project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')` 
in your gradle file and if you open the project dependency, you would see that it is using `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesVersion', '+')}"`. 
That is where the problem lies. You are using a different version in dependencies of gradle. You can either use the dependency resolution

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
    //start here
    configurations.all {
 resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
   def requested = details.requested
       if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
          details.useVersion '15.0.1'
       }
       }
     }
    //end
     jcenter()
       maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com"
       }
     }
 }
```

or can use the default `+` version for 
`implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1")`. Remember to keep the versions same.

Comment: When I tried adding the dependency resolution, I got an error in android studio saying that "Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.1."

Comment: I've updated the original post to reflect the changes that were instructed

Comment: @vk1 ya because that version of services-analytics might not be available. Instead of `15.0.1`, use `+`

Comment: It worked when I added the '+' instead of 15.0.1.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a dex issue.

As you are targeting a minSDKVersion of 19 you need to add the following to your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

I see that you have already enabled multidex in your defaultConfig, but have you made the required changes to your `MainApplication.java`?

You also need to change the following line in your `MainApplication.java` from

`public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {`

to

`public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {`

You can read more about enabling multidex here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex as there are different ways to enable it depending on whether you override the `Application` class.

Comment: Thank you for answering me.  When I combined your answer with Ankush's answer, I was able to get it to build.  At first I got an error like multidex symbol isn't recognized..then i realized I forgot to import at the top of the file.  Thanks again!