# Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, gradle

My Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mystorie.totheworld"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:+'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:+'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is the error I received

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.mystorie.totheworld, PID: 16152
>                     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
>                         at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6420)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6012)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5951)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/base.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mystorie.totheworld-1/lib/arm,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                         at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6420) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6012) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408) 
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport:
>   'socket'

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have multiple version of Google Play Services with the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
```

So, you need to remove the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

And use only one version of the library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
```

It should be remove your error

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I solved it thanks to this other answer.

[Android 3.1.1 - Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818415/android-3-1-1-failed-resolution-of-lcom-google-android-gms-common-internal-zz)

The problem is the lack of this dependency in the gradle file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you update your project to AndroidX.

Then remove

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

and make sure all of your `com.google.android.gms` dependencies are same version .