# React Native 0.60 - Unable to Run App with react-native run-android: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services, android-multidex

It's late on Friday before a long weekend, and I'm having issues running an `react-native` app. Current version is `0.60` (latest), and running the command

```
react-native run-android
```

Results in a **`debug`** build that successfully installs on my connected app, but crashes upon opening with the following error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.myApp, PID: XXXX
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq

Googling this cryptic error results in a number of results suggesting `MultiDex` to be the culprit, and how to handle this. I'll link some threads for research's sake:

[Android 3.1.1 - Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818415/android-3-1-1-failed-resolution-of-lcom-google-android-gms-common-internal-zz)

[Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467209/didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gms-common-internal-zzbq-on-path-dexpath?rq=1)
(links to previous result)

One of the solutions, namely overriding `use version` for `com.google.android.gms` if name contains `multidex` to version `12.0.1` **works for `debug` builds**:

In `android/build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "12.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this causes completely different issues for **`production`** builds:

> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label:12.0.1.
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:12.0.1
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:12.0.1
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:12.0.1

All of these are saying "Required by XXX:17.0.1", so I tried `details.useVersion "17.0.1"`, but that resulted in a similar issue:

> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.1
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.1
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.1
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.1

Some of these modules have version `17.0.1`, while others are at `17.0.2` or `17.0.0`, so a strict `use version X.Y.Z` will not work for **`release`** build.

If I remove this `subProjects { ... }` declaration and attempt to enable `MultiDex` as suggested in other answers:

In `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

This results in the same error for both `debug` and `release` builds, and a little bit of extra Googling uncovers that `MultiDex` is not required for SDK version > `27.0.0` (looks to be using `28.0.0` / `28.0.3`)

I've been banging my head against this for the entire day and haven't been able to make any progress. Has anyone seen this issue **as it pertains to React Native 0.60**?

Note: There are a couple plugins that are using these `com.google.android.gms` in my project, namely:

- `react-native-background-geolocation`

  - `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServicesLocationVersion"`
- `react-native-camera`

  - `generalImplementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:$googlePlayServicesVisionVersion"`
- `react-native-device-info`

  - `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesVersion', '16.1.0')}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to use the new bundle/build process for Android `.aab` and `.apk` files, as shown on React Native documentation. Current process that is throwing errors is as follows:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
bundleAPK (`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`)
buildReleaseAPK (`cd ./android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..`
installReleaseAPKAlt (`adb install -r ./android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk`)
```

When successful, this generates the `.apk` file and installs it on device, similar to downloading/installing directly from the Play Store. Various bugs in build process are preventing this, as detailed above.

React Native documentation suggest to use a different set of commands to generate `.aab` file, and from that the `.apk`:

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew bundleRelease
cd .. && react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Complete details can be found at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-apk. Information about generating Signed APK included since previous implementation.

Using this approach, `.aab` and `.apk` files are generated and installed on device, but another issue arises in lack of `ic_launcher_rounded`. See [React Native 0.60 - ic_launcher_round missing for Release Bundle/Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57775250/react-native-0-60-ic-launcher-round-missing-for-release-bundle-build) for details. Marking question as closed when allowed.