# React Native 0.60 - ic_launcher_round missing for Release Bundle/Build

Tags: android, react-native, release

I'm trying to generate a `release` build of a `react-native` project, and am having issues with the `ic_launcher_round.png` not being included; it is simply showing the default `android` one.

I have the following icons:

`android/app/src/main/res`:

```
- mipmap-hdpi
  - ic_launcher.png
  - ic_launcher_round.png
- mipmap-mdpi
  - ic_launcher.png
  - ic_launcher_round.png
- mipmap-xhdpi
  - ic_launcher.png
  - ic_launcher_round.png
- mipmap-xxhdpi
  - ic_launcher.png
  - ic_launcher_round.png
- mipmap-xxxhdpi
  - ic_launcher.png
  - ic_launcher_round.png
```

Also, I have rounded icons specified in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>
  ...
</application>
```

When I run `react-native run-android`, the `ic_launcher_round` is included, and I can see my custom icon displayed on device. Following the steps from `react-native` for creating a `release` build:

```
cd android
./gradlew bundleRelease
cd .. && react-native run-android --variant=release
```

This successfully bundles, builds and installs the `.apk` file onto my phone, **but without the correct icon**; it displays the default android.

Has anyone seen this issue? I can't seem to google a solution that handles this new build process (for `react-native 0.60`, using `./gradlew bundleRelease` instead of `react-native bundle` or `./gradlew assembleRelease`)

Edit: Code and all plugins have been migrated from pervious version of `react-native` and function perfectly on `debug` and `release` builds; this question is specifically about lack of icon in `release` build with current settings. Please limit comments accordingly.

Comment: Have you cleaned android with gradlew clean? 
I also often found myself having to use ./gradlew assembleRelease instead of variant release because it didn't look like it was working as a release.

Comment: Yeah, I always run `./gradlew clean` before attempting to do other things. I'll try the `assembleRelease` thing too; maybe that'll work.

Comment: @AndréPinto, hmm, no, `assembleRelease` results in a build error `Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label:12.0.1`. Related issue to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733597/react-native-0-60-unable-to-run-app-with-react-native-run-android-java-lang-n (a different question I asked a few days ago that got no traction, but that I don't encounter when using `bundleRelease`)

Comment: Did you start this project with react-native 0.60 or you upgraded it from an older version?

Also, I saw that the library `react-native-background-geolocation` has additional [configuration](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/blob/master/help/INSTALL-ANDROID-AUTO.md) for android when using it with react-native >= 0.60.

I can say I use `react-native-camera` and `react-native-device-info` with no problems in the project I am working right now, but haven't used the  `react-native-background-geolocation`  yet.

Comment: As another option, you can upgrade if you have upgraded your project, you can try and rebuild your android folder with `react-native upgrade --legacy=true`, be aware that this proccess may delete your old files so you should do a backup first.

Comment: Yeah, brand new project with `react-native 0.60`, which I then ported all my files to and re-installed all plugins at their latest version. Was a week-long process to get to this point. And yes, that additional configuration has been included and verified to be working. I've got to the point that all builds are working and all components are functioning, it's literally just the icon missing on `release` build.

Comment: is Default android icon showing into all version or device of android or is any specific versionor device in which default icon showing?

Comment: @VishalDhanotiya All devices/versions. Showing in the play store as default icon as well.

Comment: @JonGoodwin Can you provide a little more detail? I'm not sure what that even means. Note I have deleted/recreated all `ic_launcher_round.png` files, not sure what you're saying by "make them point to your ic_launcher_round." Make what point? How?

Comment: delete all references to ic_launcher *OR* a least make them point to your *ic_launcher_round*. Try..test..despair...ask

Comment: @JonGoodwin If I delete it, it uses the same icon (as that is the default Android one). I don't get any errors, the bundle is simply ignoring the icon. I've followed all the tutorials on adding and linking icons in Android, but it still uses the default one. I've tried to build this in Android Studio, but the build fails for a non-related issue. Trying to do the build process as detailed by `react-native`, the build is successful, but the icon is not linked.

Comment: As I say the icons do not **come from thin air** they are in your application resources. They are not placed there by magic. They are referenced. This is how the system works.

Comment: @JonGoodwin Ok... Where are they referenced? Specifically with regards to the `react-native` build process. Can you provide me step-by-step details on how to confirm which icon is being used/how to override it?

Comment: It does matter where the are referenced  if they don't exist. Then you will get an error **OR** it **will work**. Replace **all** icons you don't like with the one you do in **all** your resource folders. The system cannot display an icon that does not exist.

Comment: @JonGoodwin Thanks for the help. I'll let you know if your solution works or not.

Comment: you can delete res folder. then build again. 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21309

Comment: @Milon I've done that plenty of times. This is not related to the duplicate resources issue, and the issue you linked uses RN 0.57, which does not use the same bundle command as 0.60. I'm looking for specific problems/solutions with that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `res` folder in both `src/main` and `src/release` contained two files:

```
- ic_launcher_foreground.xml
- ic_launcher_background.xml
```

As well as a `drawable` folder with the same two files repeated. Simply removing these files (total of 8 files across 4 locations) and forcing the app to fallback to the `.png` files specified in the various `mipmap` folders allows the icon to display correctly in both `debug` and `release` builds.

Answer (score 1):

Rename both ic_launcher.png and ic_launcher_round.png to something else  like *my_ic_launcher.png*

Make the change in manifest:

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/my_ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/my_ic_launcher_round"
>
```

Clean and build.